# Label and List View not displaying on Widget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am busy with an assignment and I am using PyQt4 to develop a UI. 
The user should be able to log in and then be taken to a different window where they should see a Menu and two subwindows in tile format.

My windows display fine but for some reason my labels and list view widgets ain't displaying on the subwindows.

Can someone please assist?
Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import eventsvenues, login 


class Eventsvenues(QtGui.QMainWindow, eventsvenues.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = eventsvenues.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.subwindow = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.subwindow_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.subwinds()



    def subwinds(self):
        self.ui.mdiArea.addLabel.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow_2)
        self.ui.mdiArea.tileSubWindows()


class Login(QtGui.QMainWindow, login.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = login.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.login = QtGui.QPushButton()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.login, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.checklogin)
        self.events = Eventsvenues(self)

    def checklogin(self):
        if self.ui.username.text() == "Elandre" and self.ui.lineEdit_2.text() == "12345678":
           self.events.show()
        else:
            print("failed")        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Login()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Without providing the ui files it is a bit hard to understand what's going on, but I can see a clear problem anyway: you're not using `__init__` on the right class. You are calling `QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)`, but you should call `QtGui.QMainWIndow.__init__(self, parent)` instead. Also, if `self.ui.mdiArea` is a QMdiArea, it has no `addLabel` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I ended up scrapping this program and rebuilt it. My issue seem to have been with the way I imported the Ui files. 
I should have used `from eventsvenues import * ` instead of using  `import eventsvenues, login` to add both at the same time.

Comment: Also, instead of having my Login Ui be a window I made it a Dialog widget instead.

Comment: The import issue you report shouldn't have changed anything (unless you edited those files in some way, which is something that should never be done). Also, you tried to inherit from the ui classes, but you actually never used them in the correct way: when you inherit from both the QWidget subclass (QMainWindow, in your case) *and* the ui, you have to call `self.setupUi(self)`, but you created a new ui form instance, which is unnecessary in the multiple inheritance approach.